# How to style a LI after every 4th LI displayed in a 2 column/1 row view for each?

Tags: css

So I have a blog layout (theme) that displays the articles in 2 columns on a row, each article being a LI inside an UL.

[image]

I then have this CSS code that basically adds `margin-top: 20px;` to each LI starting from the third (so it doesn't add a margin to the first row and leave an empty space between them and the header) and it also adds `clear: both;` to each 2 LIs (first LI of each row).

```
.module-row.two-cols ul li:nth-child(n+3) {
    margin-top: 20px;
} 
.module-row.two-cols ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

The code for this is:

```
<div class="content-wrap module-row two-cols clearfix">
 <ul>
   <?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>  
   <li class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="item content-out co-type1">
       <?php get_template('article-column');?>
     </div>
   </li>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
 </ul>
</div>
```

My problem starts with the CSS when I try to insert an ad LI after every 4th LI - so it will basically display an ad after every 2 rows/4 columns. Is there a way to change the CSS so I can insert that ad correctly and also keep the current CSS logic (with the top margin and clear)? Also, the ad LI will be with one with the class col-sm-12 (so full width).

So I want this, with CSS if possible

[image]

Basically insert via the PHP code another LI with class col-sm-12 after each fourth col-sm-6 LI. Thanks!

I can do this in PHP, change the theme's logic and do the count there, not via CSS, but I want to know if possible to do it via CSS because I would like best to not change the theme, only CSS. "Hacking" it and doing it via PHP instead of CSS will look like this - so this is the logic I want in CSS:

[image]

**Add a `margin-top` to all the LIs after the 3rd LI, add a `clear: both` from each 2 to 2 LIs starting from the first LI and add both `margin-top` and `clear: both` to each 5th LI.**

Comment: Please add your html

Comment: Provide your HTML

Comment: Done, sorry for not providing.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Which version?@Courtney Mill solution is not bad (you pointed out her HTML problem and you are right), but the logic is correct, I think. However you said that you have a CSS problem, but if you are using bootstrap, `col-sm-12` is a correct class to do what you want so I don't understand very well this "css problem" you have. Could you add some more information about this, please? Thank you.

Comment: The problem is not bootstrap related, I know the bootstrap class is correct, but I have problems with the custom CSS used to build the theme on the bootstrap framework. The logic in Courtney's answer is good, but the count is bad... but that's not the problem, I would want this to be CSS related as I know the PHP part already. Updated the question anyway to make it more clear :)

Comment: Provide a [mcve], which you are supposed to, not just code fragments.

Comment: I think what I've posted in the description now should be more than enough to understand...

Comment: @ChinaWhite It is not only about what to understand, no one should have to create the code you ask about to either test it or show a solution, you should provide one. This is very well stated in [ask]

Comment: No one HAS TO, but anyone is free to help if he wants to, and on the other hand, if I could provide the answer to my own question, I wouldn't be here, wouldn't I?

Comment: @ChinaWhite No, you don't _have_ to follow SO guidelines, don't be surprised though, if you get both downvotes and no proper answers.

Comment: if the layout is generated by the server side code, then how can we recreate the issue, Try providing a code snippet with only css and html layout you have to reproduce the issue, the code provided right now is of no help to you or anyone trying to help.

Comment: @ChinaWhite don't get angry, please. :-) LGSon is right. If you put a Minimal, Complete... etc etc example we can help you better. For now we can only speculate about what you really want. :-)

Comment: Come on man, how can you miss it? It's how to/is it possible to add a margin-top to all the LIs after the 3rd LI, add a clear: both from each 2 to 2 LIs starting from the first LI and add both margin-top and clear: both to each 5th LI. If you can't get that from an explanation accompanied by a drawing, maybe you shouldn't be answering questions here. Really.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution.
The idea is that with help of modulo operation, you can target the third while loop, 6th, 9th and so far. I am not a php developer so I hope I hope there is no syntax mistake in here if so would appreciate if someone points me to it! :)

EDIT: made a quick fix

EDIT: The HTML structure is not correct, but I do not know what you want to achieve with the li and divs at the end result so I left it the way you wrote it in the question.

```
<div class="content-wrap module-row two-cols clearfix">
 <ul>
   <?php $counter = 0 ?>
   <?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ($counter % 3 == 0){
         <div class="col">
       // code for your ad here
         </div>
    <?php } else {?>
   <li class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="item content-out co-type1">
       <?php get_template( 'row' );?>
     </div>
   </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php $counter = $counter + 1 ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, I think the problem with your code is that you can't have a DIV inside an UL element (only if it's nested in a LI), only LI elements, and if I change that DIV to LI it will obviously trigger the CSS I already have in place and it will break the layout. For the adding the LI part I can already add the LI inside PHP using (as per in your example) $counter  = 1 ... if($counter % 4 == 0) { ad LI here } ... $counter++, but the problem is with the CSS...

Comment: So I'm guessing unless there's a CSS "hack" so I can make for example a defined LI class be skipped from the nth-child selector definition, or some logic to alter the CSS to take into consideration every new 5th LI added I don't know (not that great with CSS beyond the basic stuff)... I am also thinking maybe replicating the css logic in php and handling the ad LI there... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Correct. I didn't actually read the html part of the code, only changed the php and added the condition. I'm quite confused to what you want to achieve as I don't really know what the end result would look like but hope you've figured it out.

Comment: I've updated the description maybe I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: If you don't know what the asker wants, don't post an answer.

Comment: @LGSon I can still post an answer to what was asked without having to understand what it is supposed to do at the end.